# ng-repeat values with 3 columns in table? - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to display data in 3 column table format.

With the below code am able to get data in 3 column format but I want it in proper table, with tr and td.

```
 <body ng:app="myApp" ng:controller="myCtrl">
    <span ng:repeat="(index, value) in array">
        {{value}}<br ng:show="(index+1)%3==0" />
    </span>
</body>
```

and

```
    lvar app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.array = ["opt1","opt2","opt3","opt4","opt5","opt6","opt7"];
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JG3A5/

I tried but with ng-repeat I'm not able to achieve it properly. Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: You're using the repeat syntax for an object, arrays are simply `item in items` - are you able to change the format of your data?

Comment: You can use 'track by $index' instead to get the index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can change your data format, it'd certainly be easier to have an array of arrays, each inner array representing a row:

```
$scope.data = [
    ["opt1", "opt2", "opt3"],
    ["opt1", "opt2", "opt3"],
    ["opt1", "opt2", "opt3"]
];
```

You could then do a simple inner `ng-repeat`

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
        <td ng-repeat="column in row">{{column}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JG3A5/75/